# Brothers Android sdk not detecting wireless printers

Tags: android, wifi-direct, brother-print-sdk, wifi-print

I am currently utilizing Brother Android SDK v4.67, and while I can successfully connect to the printer using wireless direct, I am seeking a solution to connect to the printer through a shared Wi-Fi network instead.